# Explain sorting in Solr with multiple sort clauses

Tags: sorting, solr, lucene, explain

Imagine there's a Solr request with multiple sort clauses (not on score obviously). Is there a way to figure out, for every found document, which of those clauses resulted in a tie with neighbours and which were actually used for sorting? I'm especially interested in one clause and want to find all documents reordered because of it.

For example, I have `sort=A desc, B asc, C asc` with three documents found and I need to find out which are reordered based on `B asc`:

```
Doc 1: perhaps we skip it
Doc 2: "B asc" meaning it has same A value with Doc 1 and B was used as tie breaker.
Doc 3: "A desc" meaning it has different A value from Doc 2 and therefore B was never used for sorting.
```

Obviously there are multiple ways around this.

- Is there explainResults-like mechanism that explains sorting instead of score?
- Is there a way of specifying two sort= parameters, sorting the same docset with two different set of clauses, having them both in response, then I can compare the docsets?
- Is there a direct way to get a deciding sort clause for every pair of response documents?
- Maybe there's some Search Component that can do that? How hard would it be to write?
- Of course, failing that, I might just do two Solr requests (with and without sort clause that I care about) and compare the results, obviously I don't want to do that performance-wise...

Comment: Comparing one document to another to determine which field was the deciding one doesn't seem too terribly complicated to do on your own, assuming your sort fields are stored. Just something like: `if (doc1.A != doc2.A then A; else if (doc1.B != doc2.B then B; else C;))`

Comment: @femtoRgon I don't have the same sorting every day. Yesterday it could be "A desc" now it "C asc" and tomorrow it is a formula, making replication tricky.

Answer (score 1):

The nearest thing I can think of is [query re-ranking](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Query+Re-Ranking). So you would put your special sort into that, possibly using *val* keyword to convert expected query into the score derived from the field value. But that only works with numerics or functions.

Additionally, the sort parameter would still override that as reranking influences the original score. So you would have to move everything into the scoring function instead. Which could be problematic if you sort by text fields.

So, this may not really be worth doing in-Solr. If you can do it with double query, it will probably be the easiest path forward.